# Have to run glob.glob twice to work (Python3)

Tags: python, glob

I am trying to grab all of the mp3 files in my Downloads directory (after procedurally downloading them) and move them to a new file. However, anytime I try to use glob to grab a list of the available .mp3 files, I have to glob twice for it to work properly (the first time it is running it returns an empty list). Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

```
import glob
import os
import shutil

newpath = r'localpath/MP3s' 
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)

list_of_files = glob.glob('localpath/Downloads/*.mp3')

for i in list_of_files:
    shutil.move(i, newpath)
```

Comment: What's the current behavior of your code?

Comment: That is strange.  So you run this program and it sees no files, then you run the same program the same way, and the second time it sees and copies files?  How many times have you reproduced this behavior?  Could it be a timing thing, like are you running something that puts the .mp3 files there right before you run this program?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue.

Comment: I suggest using pathlib instead!!

Comment: Timing seems like the most logical problem I can see. The first time I run the script, the files are downloaded properly into my downloads folder. Then when it tries to pull the names of the new mp3 files into list_of_files, it finds nothing. However, if the files are already in the download folder when I run the file, it is able to grab them and move them just fine. I'm guessing the files are still downloading when it moves on to the next piece of code.
Edit: Threw in a time.sleep() after the download command and it works perfectly! Thanks for the suggestions everyone

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a timing issue. The files I was trying to access were still in the process of downloading, with is why the glob was returning empty. I inserted a `time.sleep(5)` before the glob, and it is now running smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

**May I suggest an alternate approach**

```py
from pathlib import Path
from shutil import move

music = Path("./soundtrack")
# you can include absolute paths  too...
newMusic = Path("./newsoundtrack")

# makes new folder specified in newMusic
newMusic.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

# will select all
list_of_files = music.glob("*")
# u want to select only mp3's do:
# list_of_files = music.glob("*.mp3")

for file in list_of_files:
    move(str(file), str(newMusic))
```